# Stop scrolling effect happening when going up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi guys so i have a simple effect when a person scrolls down content will fly in from the left and right etc. However what i want to happen is that when the user scrolls back up, the content stays the same, so the effect only happens one time per refresh if that make sense :)

```
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6" data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-easing="ease-in-sine">
       <h1> 1</h1>
       <span class="border"></span>
       <p> 2 </p>
        </div>
     <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6" data-aos="fade-left" data-aos-easing="ease-in-sine">
     <img src="Images/number1.png" style="padding-top: 20px;">
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
       AOS.init({
  duration: 1200,
})
```

I have used this plugin [Link](https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/) For the effects

Thanks

Comment: Without an interactive example demonstrating the issue, I doubt someone will be able to solve your problem. Can you make a JSFiddle?

Comment: Have you looked at the library on github. There is a `data-aos-once` .. Which seems to do exactly what you want. ..  https://github.com/michalsnik/aos

Comment: @Our_Benefactors somoene did thanks x

Comment: @Daniel ye i just need to do more reading next time :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like there is a attribute you can add to your element

`data-aos-once="true"`

that can be added to keep the item from animating a second time.

https://github.com/michalsnik/aos#-advanced-settings